# Dynamic SQL Execution Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting Quotes error while Executing below Quotes.I replaced hard-code value with double quotes

```
 declare @query nvarchar(MAX)
    set @query = 'SELECT PID AS EID,
    ''637'' + p.SSN + SPACE(9- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(p.SSN,'')))))
    + ''98''
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 12)
    + SPACE(9)
    + ''A1''
    + @Str1
    + @Str2
    + ISNULL(LEFT(UPPER(@Str1),30),'') + SPACE(30- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(LEFT(@Str1,30),'''')))))
    + ISNULL(LEFT(UPPER(@Str2),30),'') + SPACE(30- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(LEFT(@Str2,30),'''')))))
    + SPACE(1)
    + SPACE(8) AS Data, GETDATE() AS CreatedOn
    INTO #Temp
    FROM dbo.PERSON p'

    exec sp_executesql @query;



INSERT INTO  dbo.RKS_TransactionData
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Even if the query executed successfully, this approach will not work. Your temp table exists within the scope of the dynamic execution only and will be immediately dropped after that statement is executed. More importantly, there is no need to use dynamic sql at all here - this can be written as plain ole static sql.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `isnull()` you need `''''` in `isnull()` (already you have done but partially) :

```
 declare @query nvarchar(MAX)

 set @query = 'SELECT PID AS EID,
    ''637'' + p.SSN + SPACE(9- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(p.SSN,'''')))))
    + ''98''
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 12)
    + SPACE(9)
    + ''A1''
    + @Str1
    + @Str2
    + ISNULL(LEFT(UPPER(@Str1),30),'''') + SPACE(30- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(LEFT(@Str1,30),'''')))))
    + ISNULL(LEFT(UPPER(@Str2),30),'''') + SPACE(30- LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(LEFT(@Str2,30),'''')))))
    + SPACE(1)
    + SPACE(8) AS Data, GETDATE() AS CreatedOn
    INTO #Temp
    FROM dbo.PERSON p'

    print @query -- see how query looks or try to compile query

    exec sp_executesql @query;
```